# Bluetooth programming in python

Tags: python, bluetooth

Are there any nice Python libraries for Bluetooth programming? I tried PyBluez, but Eclipse doesn't recognize the module Bluetooth. Can anyone suggest tutorials for Python and Bluetooth?

Comment: can you `import bluetooth` from the regular interpreter?

Comment: Now i have found a good python bluetooth library lightblue. But when i try to sent file to my nokia 5310, it shows operation failed. Sometimes when programmed with interpreter it works fine. But when run as a .py file it wont. Anyone plz help me with this....

Thanx in advance...

Comment: @jvc, do you mean that the sending of the file failed, or that it succeeded but the import failed, or that something else failed...? If the latter, add some prints or use the debugger. Either say, sounds like a new question, about Python on nokia 5310.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it personally, but I hope to try this cross platform bluetooth python api: [Lightblue](http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: From their site: *This project is no longer maintained.*

Answer (score 7):

PyBluez now supports Python 3, so it may work for you now.

Python 3.3 and above has inbuilt support for Bluetooth though [sockets](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socket.html). While there is native support, *many* features of PyBluez are not available in native Python 3 sockets. For example, you cannot use inquiry scans or SDP.

I created a [tutorial](http://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/) describing the differences between using PyBluez vs. Python 3 sockets for a simple Bluetooth application.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently experimenting with scapy in python.  I have worked out how to send a packet via srbt1 command and i am currently fuzzing the protocol.

```
packet = fuzz(L2CAP_Hdr('1111111111111111111111111111111'))
srbt1("20:21:A5:82:44:01",packet,0)
```

**Explanation**

- srbt1 << sends the BT packet.
- "20:21:A5:82:44:01" << defines the device you want to connect to
- packet << defines the payload
- 0 << defines my BT card.

I hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention your nokia phone, you might like this book: http://www.mobilepythonbook.org/

The examples page (which i cant link directly for some reason) contains an example for using PySerial over bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently used Pybluez with good results, you can find the git here.
https://github.com/karulis/pybluez

And you can find a neat and helpful tutorial here a neat tutorial here.
https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c212.html

If you are using Windows, you'll need to have Visual C++, more details on the git page.

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Answer (score 0):

If the interactive mode of gatttool (part of Bluez) works for you then [Pygatt](https://github.com/peplin/pygatt/) is a nice wrapper around this tool. Well maintained. Uses pexpect to interact with gatttool. Also wraps "hcitool lescan" to scan for Bluetooth devices. Basic usage example:

```
import pygatt.backend
adapter = pygatt.backends.GATTToolBackend()
adapter.start()
device = adapter.connect('xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx', 5, 'random')
device.char_write_handle(0x23,[0x20, 0x21])
device.subscribe('00008a22-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',callback = mycallback, indication=True)
```