# Bluetooth for Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bluetooth

What is the best way to do bluetooth programming for Python 2.7?

I tried using [pybluez](https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/), but the downloads appear to go up to only Python 2.6. I also tried downloading the tarball with the source and running `python setup.py build`, but it failed with an error message stating `Can't find the Windows XP Platform SDK` (I'm running Windows 8)

I also looked at [lightblue](http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/), but while it supports Linux and Macs, it doesn't support Windows. The website also states it's no longer maintained.

Python 3.3 and above apparently supports bluetooth using the [socket](http://kevindoran1.blogspot.co.nz/2013/04/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3.html) module (via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3238558/646543) SO answer), but I'm using 2.7.

None of the existing solutions I found appear to work for me. Is there some other library that I can try that supports Python 2.7, or is there some way I can use any of the above despite the problems listed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the alternative binaries at [www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pybluez](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pybluez)

Answer (score 0):

to build pybluez from source (or using pip) on windows, it is first necessary to install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 (VCForPython27.msi)

available from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)
or [here](http://aka.ms/vcpython27)

I have found this package to be useful for many pip installs, so it is not a bad package to have installed for future use.